# Can I configure a Dataflow job to be single threaded?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, concurrency, pipeline, dataflow, single-threaded

I was trying to configure and deploy a Cloud Dataflow job that is truly single threaded to avoid concurrency issues while creating/updating entities in the datastore. I was under the assumption that using an n1-standard-1 machine ensures that the job is running on a single thread, on a single machine, but I have come to learn the hard that this is not the case.

I have gone over the suggestions mentioned in an earlier query here- [Can I force a step in my dataflow pipeline to be single-threaded (and on a single machine)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57360621/can-i-force-a-step-in-my-dataflow-pipeline-to-be-single-threaded-and-on-a-singl/60833930#60833930)

But I wanted to avoid implementing a windowing approach around this, and wanted to know if there is a simpler way to simply configure a job to ensure single threaded behavior.

Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Are you in streaming mode (PubSub source) ? or in batch mode?

Comment: If you're using an unbounded source you will need a window anyway. Please let me know more details about your pipeline

Comment: I'm using Kafka as my streaming source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have come to learn recently that single threaded behavior is guaranteed by using a single worker which is n1-standard-1 and additionally using the following exec_arg --numberOfWorkerHarnessThreads=1 as this restricts the number of JVM threads to 1 as well.

Comment: yes adding exec_arg --numberOfWorkerHarnessThreads=1 solved it

Comment: I also having the same problem. Now I understand what needs to be done. Thanks.